# Nodejs: Mongoose (mongodb) select and save 3000 items take a long time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my code:

```
for (const element of data) {
        let find = await Coin.findOne({name: element.coin, network: element.network});
        if (!find) {
            new Coin({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                name: element.coin,
                title: element.name,
                network: element.network,
                contract: element.contract
            }).save()
        }
    }
```

But this code take time about 2 minutes for 3000 items!

Comment: Reading and writing one document at a time in a loop can take time, because you are sending and receiving data between your program code and the database server. You can try this - make this efficient by using bulk write operation and using upsert update option. Refer this: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/

Answer (score 0):

you  are trying to insert data using loop and also your making new query every time to collection , which makes the process time-consuming as it involves opening connection and logging, creating indexes in background . so first we need to optimise the process at our end, let mongo their own method to bulk data using its own method

```js
exports.bulkUpdateInsert = (data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Tag(Co)
      .bulkWrite(data)
      .then((doc) => {
        resolve(doc);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

Use the above code snippet to make it efficient